# Multiple updates or full document replace

Tags: mongodb

I need to make two updates to a mongodb document that can be loaded by key.
Two updates are $sets but one of the updates is unconditional and the other is conditional.
To my understand I've two options:

- Load all the document, do the updates and then do a complete document replace with the modified version
- Do two separate update commands, one with the condition and other without.

In general what is better in terms of performance?
Is there a big penalty on document replace? The penalty is only in network bandwitch and bson parsing? Or it's also on index updating and other hidden costs?

Note: The document can be about 10Kb of data and have 4 index. None of the index is affected by the update.

Comment: Could you clarify your two approaches by including sample code in the question? What is the condition?